# transitionend method to animate a infinite slider with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm new to this community and first of all, I take this opportunity to thank all of you for the wonderful work you do every day.

I'm trying to create an infinite manual carousel, in the Netflix style, this is the link to the codepen of everything I have done so far:
https://codepen.io/A12584r/pen/OjvWYp?fref=gc

Here is the relevant javascript:

```
    let prendiContenitoreGalleria = document.querySelector('.contenitore-galleria'),
    prendiArticle = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.contenitore-galleria__article')),
    contaArticle = prendiArticle.length,
    prendiImmagini = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.contenitori__img')),
    prendiFrecciaSinistra = document.querySelector('.freccia-sinistra'),
    prendiFrecciaDestra = document.querySelector('.freccia-destra');
prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.width = 100 * contaArticle + '%';
for (let numeroImmagini = 0; numeroImmagini < prendiImmagini.length; numeroImmagini++) {
    prendiImmagini[numeroImmagini].style.width = 100 / contaArticle + '%';
}
prendiContenitoreGalleria.insertBefore(prendiArticle[contaArticle - 1], prendiArticle[0]);
prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.marginLeft = '-' + 100 + '%';
function andareADestra () {
    prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.marginLeft = '-' + 200 + '%';
    prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.transitionDuration = '.7s';
    prendiContenitoreGalleria.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
        prendiContenitoreGalleria.appendChild(prendiArticle[0]);
        prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.marginLeft = '-' + 100 + '%';
    }, false);
}
function andareASinistra () {
    prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.marginLeft = 0;
    prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.transitionDuration = '.7s';
    prendiContenitoreGalleria.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
        prendiContenitoreGalleria.insertBefore(prendiArticle[contaArticle - 1], prendiArticle[0]);
        prendiContenitoreGalleria.style.marginLeft = '-' + 100 + '%';
    }, false);
}
prendiFrecciaSinistra.addEventListener('click', function () {
    andareASinistra();
});
prendiFrecciaDestra.addEventListener('click', function () {
    andareADestra();
});
```

I have tried to use the vanilla Javascript transitionend events and what I want to achieve is that when clicking on the right arrow of the carousel the first article is put in place of the third and vice versa, when clicking on the left arrow of the carousel the last article is put in place of the first one.

For this purpose I use marginLeft to move between the articles in my carousel which are 3 and the divs that contains them (these are 3 too) has a width of 300% set via JavaScript.

My problem is that when I click on the carousel arrows, the transition is done but it does a strange effect coming back to its original location immediately.

Any one of you could help me to figure out where I'm wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In your two functions to move left and right, `andareASinistra` and `andareADestra` you are adding an event listener for the `transitionend` event.

The handler for this is removing the margin-left offset by resetting it to `-100%` after each move left or right.

You can confirm this is the problem by editing the inline style of the `id="contenitore-galleria"` element, if you set `style="margin-left: 0"` then the carousel is moved, then returned to the `-100%` position.

So the reason it is happening is because that is what you are explicitly telling it to! Delete the lines from both  `andareASinistra` and `andareADestra`

`rendiContenitoreGalleria.style.marginLeft = '-' + 100 + '%';`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i've just set the margin-left: 0; css property of #contenitore-galleria element in my css file but the problem persists. In my two functions andareASinistra and andareADestra, I first set the corresponding margin-left values ​​and then, at the end of the transition, I reported the margin-left values ​​to -100% so that they show me the right article at all times. Is my mistake exactly in this?
Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: You misunderstand - what I meant is if I change the value inline in the codepen example (not using the buttons) then the carousel snaps back - because this is what you are telling it to do...see my edit.